Police officer falls for sister of person he killed
I was watching "Shades of Blue" (please don't judge) and they started a plot line where the rookie cop starts a relationship with the sister of the guy he killed and I thought "wait, a second I've seen this recently in another show".  But I cannot remember the TV show. 
I recall the following details of the show. It aired in the past 2-3 years on ABC or NBC, and I'm like 90% sure it is no longer on the air (it's been cancelled). The entire show revolves around the lives of maybe 5-6 police officers. 
The white police officer involved in this relationship shoots and kills a young black boy who he thought had a gun. He feels guilty about the shooting and begins to hang around the family/sister to try and help them. He starts to date the sister after, but her family doesn't like it so several other members attack him to encourage him to end the relationship.  In the end, he stops seeing her because he was beaten up. 
Does anyone know what show this plot is from?

It was a plot line from season three of Rookie Blue, starting from episode 3 - A Good Shoot. According to the Wikipedia page it was broadcast in the US on ABC.
The white cop (Dov) shoots a black kid who he thought had a gun during the robbery of a store. Feeling guilty he originally takes groceries to the kid's sister, and eventually they start a relationship. It eventually ends when Dov is beaten up.
Unfortunately the IMDB episode descriptions seem to gloss over that entire plotline, and it's been a few years since I watched it, so I don't recall exactly which episodes the story played out in - I'd guess the first half of that season though.

Oh yeah, that's it! Thanks much!
